# How to record time simulation in OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++

I am running two different simulation with different hosts number and I want to compare the simulation time, how can I get the field simulation time in scalar record results?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Usually the simulation time is determined in advance by the user (i.e. `sim-time-limit`) so it is not a result of the simulation. If you have some specific stopping condition that stops the simulation then you should write out also the actual simulation time manually as a scalar somewhere in a `finish()` method.

On the other hand if you are interested in the wall-clock time the simulation takes to finish, you should measure that also manually as that is not the property of the simulation, but rather depend on the effectiveness of the compiler, the speed of your CPU etc. Still in this case, you have to manually measure that time and write it out.